# How to display date field in format as month/year and pass it to controller

Tags: visualforce

I need a help where i need to display date field in format as month/year for user input and pass the value it to controller from vf page to save it in a date data type field.

Regards

Comment: Can't we just let them select a date but in controller we will get the month and Year from that date and save that value in fields?

Comment: You need Jquery you can't do with salesforce picklist.. Jquery example http://jsfiddle.net/Ratan_Paul/guxjqjtx/

Comment: Ratan.. How to pass it to controller..

Comment: Sid in your page take `<input name="startDate" id="startDate" class="date-picker" />` and in controller you can use `apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('startDate')`  use name `startDate` to get the value

Comment: Hi Ratan..Thnx for the reply.. I tried this .. i am able to get the value.. But in my vf page i have dynamic created date rows..Can u tell me how to loop and get all the values..

Comment: for each row `<input name="startDate__{!recordId}" id="startDate" class="date-picker" />` and in controller use for loop to iterate your list and inside use `apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('startDate__'+recordId)` .. Basically create dynamic name using record Id and do same in controller iterate over list and based on Id get the value of there respective month and year.

Comment: What is recordId?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35166/discussion-between-ratan-and-sid).

Comment: RecordId is.. you may be using list to iterate for example `list<Account>` then use `Accountid` because it will be always unique for each row